# Can I make a reusable classes object in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

If I have objects styles binding in a component and I want to use the same objects to bind styles in another component, then can I extract these objects into a reusable component or file? Something like this:

`styles.vue`

```
<script setup>

const flexColumn = {
    "d-flex": true,
    "flex-column": true,
};
const rowMB5 = {
    row: true,
    "mb-5": true,
};

const rowMT5 = {
    row: true,
    "mt-5": true,
};

const rowItemsCenter = {
    row: true,
    "align-items-center": true,
};

const fs08LightGrayish = {
    fontSize08Rem: true,
    colorLightGrayish: true,
};

const fs09LightGrayish = {
    fontSize09Rem: true,
    colorLightGrayish: true,
};

const blackishBold = {
    colorBlackish: true,
    "fw-bold": true,
};
const btnPrimary = {
    btn: true,
    "text-white": true,
    bgBluish: true,
    "fw-bold": true,
    fontSize09Rem: true,
};

const blueishBoldFs09 = {
    fontSize09Rem: true,
    "fw-bold": true,
};

const colMD2BlueishBold09 = {
    "col-md-2": true,
    colorBlueish: true,
    "fw-bold": true,
    fontSize09Rem: true,
};

const colMD3Fs08 = {
    fontSize08Rem: true,
    "col-md-3": true,
};

const colMd3FlexEvenlyCenter = {
    "col-md-3": true,
    "d-flex": true,
    "align-items-center": true,
    "justify-content-between": true,
};

const coldMD4flexColumnGap3 = {
    "col-md-4": true,
    "d-flex": true,
    "flex-column": true,
    "gap-3": true,
};

const colMD3FlexJustifyEndFs09Bold = {
    "col-md-3": true,
    "d-flex": true,
    colorBlackish: true,
    "justify-content-end": true,
    fontSize09Rem: true,
    "fw-bold": true,
};

const colMD4Fs08 = {
    "col-md-4": true,
    fontSize08Rem: true,
};

const colMD5UpcomingEvent = {
    "col-md-5": true,
    upcomingEvent: true,
};
</script>
```

And then export these objects for reusability so I can use it in another component, like `styles.flexColumn`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move everything into an ordinal JS file with exports:

styles.js

```
export const flexColumn = {
    "d-flex": true,
    "flex-column": true,
};
```

Then import into a component when needed:

```
<script setup>
import {flexColumn} from './styles';
</script>
<template>
  <div :style="flexColumn"></div>
</template>
```

You can import all styles into an object:

```
<script setup>
import * as styles from './styles';
</script>
<template>
  <div :style="styles.flexColumn"></div>
</template>
```